# show the previous fragment on hitting icon in action bar?

Tags: android, button, android-fragments, android-actionbar

How do i show the previous button when user hits my icon on action bar . I know i can remove the existing one and add the previous fragment but is there any other simple way ? Basically i want my back button the action bar to act like standard back button (i.e show the previous fragment ) .

Thanks in advance .

Comment: Delete the "back button in the action bar", as it is not necessary, since the user already has access to a back button. You can even read about this anti-pattern in the Android Design guidelines: http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/pure-android.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

iOS platform use an explicit back button with label to allow the user to navigate up the application's hierarchy.

[image]

Instead, Android uses the main action bar's app icon for hierarchical navigation and the navigation bar's back button for temporal navigation. Please review the [Navigation pattern](http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/navigation.html).

[image]

You have to follow this guideline to provide a consistent navigation experience across the platform, so I advice you to delete your back button in the action bar.